# Customize routerLink in Angular 5

Tags: angular5, routerlink, angular-routerlink

In my application I am using routerLink to create my link as per according to parameter passed in routerLink.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home/global/userprofile',UserId]">
```

Above code generate links with the userId provided, but I want to customize angular routerLink so that I can check if UserId is valid or not, if valid I will return the converted href link throught this and if not I will return blank or null url.

I can not use any other directive approach or pipe factories as I am using this routerLink code in several places in my project so I just not want to go and change each and every where that code is writtern. Can anyone guide me in this? I just need concept, I can write code for the idea.

If required, I can explain it more if any queries for this.

Comment: can Router Guards help in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `routerLink` directive, I suggest You to use a programmatical redirection in your component class, like this:

**HTML component file**

```
<a (click)="goToUserProfile(UserId)">Some link</a>
```

**TS Component class:**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

goToUserProfile(userId: number) {
    if (/* userId verification*/) {
        this.router.navigate(['/home/global/userprofile', userId]);
    }
    // do nothing
}
```

Otherwise, you can use a router guard, here are some useful links:

- [Angular Routing and navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router)
- [Using Route Guards](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Right click and opening in a new tab wont work with this solution. Achor links should use href to navigate